# ES6 object namespacing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I came across some syntax I haven't seen before. When I deal with objects and when using React, you can simplify namespacing by doing such as

`let {someProp} = prevProps`

Doing this allows me to avoid writing `prevProps.someProp` everytime I want to use it.

What I don't understand is this syntax

```
let {someProp: oldData} = prevProps
```

`console.log(someProp)` will show the value of the `prevPros.someProp` but **WHERE** does `oldData` come from???

`console.log(olddata)` above this line will show `undefined` but `console.log(oldData)` underneath will show the previous props.

Comment: `let {someProp} = prevProps` is the same as `let someProp = prevProps.someProp;`. `let {someProp: oldData} = prevProps` is the same as  `let oldData = prevProps.someProp;`

Answer (score 3):

`let {someProp: myAlias} = prevProps`

This syntax allows you use an alias, for example you can use `myAlias` in your code, instead `someProp`, it is called **Object destructuring**

As stated in the comments by @FelixKling [here is the official reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

Example from provided link:

```
let o = {p: 42, q: true};
let {p: foo, q: bar} = o;

console.log(foo); // 42 
console.log(bar); // true
```

Comment: @HenryLee: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
let {someProp} = prevProps
```

is similar to this:

```
let someProp = prevProps.someProp;
```

And this:

```
let {someProp: oldData} = prevProps
```

would be similar to this:

```
let oldData = prevProps.someProp
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names)

Basically you are **destructuring** prevProps and in this case `oldData` will now be have the value of `someProp`

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is one of the shiny new things in ES6 called **object destructuring**.

Here's an elaborate example on how you can use destructuring in different ways

```
const person = {
  first: 'Jack',
  last: 'Daniels',
  address: {
    city: 'Dallas',
  }
};

// destructure as it is
const { first, last } = person;

// destructure with custom name
const { first: firstName, last: lastName } = person;

// destructure with default value
const { first, last, middle = 'The Boss' } = person;

// destructure with custom name and default value
const { first, last, middle: middleName = 'The Boss' } = person;

// destructure nested keys
const { first, last, address: { city } } = person;

// destructure nested keys with custom name
const { first, last, address: { city: myCity } } = person;

// destructure nested keys safely
const { first, last, address: { city } = {} } = person;

// destructure rest of the values
const { first, ...rest } = person; // => rest will have all keys but first
```